# Recursive search on Node Tree with Linq and Queue

Tags: c#, recursion, unit-testing, tree

I've created a `Node` class which contains two important properties:

- `public Node Parent { get; private set; }`
- `private List<Node> Children { get; set;}`

As the name suggests, the `Parent` object holds information about the **ancestor** of a certain node, if the parent is the **root** of the tree, then the parent is set to `null`. And the `Children` collection stores all the **descendant** nodes.

The methods responsible for the searching are:

- `GetChildren()`
- `GetChildrenRecursive()`

All of them are described on the code documentation. **But I am specially concerned about the performance and reliability of the searching algorithm and the overall implementation of the tree structure**. I'd like to hear some opinions on how I could possibly improve the code quality or any reading material about searching algorithms on trees.

- Node.cs

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents a tree-like structure
/// </summary>
public class Node
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The ancestor (parent) of this node. Null if the current node is the root of the tree.
    /// </summary>
    public Node Parent { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The descendats (children) of this node.
    /// </summary>
    private List<Node> Children { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks wheter the current node is the root of the tree.
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsRoot { get { return Parent != null; } }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks wheter the current node has any children.
    /// </summary>
    public bool HasChildren { get { return Count > 0; } }

    /// <summary>
    /// The current node's children count.
    /// </summary>
    public int Count { get { return Children?.Count ?? 0; } }

    /// <summary>
    /// The object stored in the current node.
    /// </summary>
    public object Value { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new instance of the <see cref="Node"/> class with an empty object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">The value that will be held by this node</param>
    public Node()
    {
        Value = new object();
        Children = new List<Node>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new instance of the <see cref="Node"/> class with a set value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">The value that will be held by this node</param>
    public Node(object value)
    {
        Value = value;
        Children = new List<Node>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a copy of all values contained in this <see cref="Node"/>.
    /// <para>
    /// Useful for avoiding interferences between instances of the <see cref="Node"/> class.
    /// </para>
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>A <see cref="Node"/> with the property values of this node</returns>
    public Node DeepCopy()
    {
        var other = (Node)MemberwiseClone();

        other.Children = new List<Node>(collection: Children);
        other.Parent = Parent?.DeepCopy();
        other.Value = new Node(value: Value);

        return other;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds a child to this <see cref="Node"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="node">The node to be added</param>
    public void AddChild(Node node)
    {
        if (node != this && node.Parent == null)
        {
            node.Parent = this;

            Children.Add(node);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes a child from this <see cref="Node"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="node">The node to be removed</param>
    public void RemoveChild(Node node)
    {
        if (node != this && Children.Contains(node))
        {
            Children.Remove(node);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Performs a superficial search, returning the children on the first level.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>An <see cref="IEnumerable{Node}"/>containing the search result</returns>
    public IEnumerable<Node> GetChildren()
    {
        return Children.AsEnumerable();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Performs a recursive search, returning all the children on all levels
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>An <see cref="IEnumerable{Node}"/>containing the search result</returns>
    public IEnumerable<Node> GetChildrenRecursive()
    {         
        var root = DeepCopy();

        // No descendants have children. No recursion neeeded.
        if (root.Children.All(x => x.Children.Count == 0))
        {
            return GetChildren();
        }
        // Some (or all) descendants have children. Use recursion
        else
        {
            var allChildren = new List<Node>();
            var searchQueue = new Queue<Node>();

            // Adds the first generation of children into the queue
            GetChildren().ToList()
                .ForEach((x) => searchQueue.Enqueue(x));

            // Loops until the queue is empty
            while (searchQueue.Any())
            {
                // Adds the first children in the queue to the final collection
                allChildren.Add(searchQueue.Peek());

                // Checks if the first children in the queue has descendants
                if (searchQueue.Peek().HasChildren)
                {
                    // Adds the descendants of the children being searched on the queue
                    searchQueue.Peek().Children
                        .ForEach((x) => searchQueue.Enqueue(x));
                }

                // Removes the first node on the queue, since it has been searched already.
                searchQueue.Dequeue();
            }

            return allChildren;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Override for the <code><see cref="object"/>.ToString()</code> method
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The string representation of this node's value</returns>
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Value?.ToString()}";
    }
}
```

Also, I'm including some tests I've made, all of them are passing as of now.

- NodeTest.cs

```
[TestClass]
public class NodeTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Node_DeepCopy_CopySuccessful()
    {
        // Arrange
        var root = new Node(null);

        var node1 = new Node(null);
        var node2 = new Node(null);

        var copyNode = new Node(null);

        // Act
        root.AddChild(node1);
        root.AddChild(node2);

        copyNode = root.DeepCopy();
        var actual = copyNode.HasChildren;

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(true, actual);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Node_DeepCopy_CopyIsIndependent()
    {
        // Arrange
        var root = new Node(null);

        var node1 = new Node(null);
        var node2 = new Node(null);

        var copyNode = new Node(null);

        // Act
        root.AddChild(node1);
        root.AddChild(node2);

        copyNode = root.DeepCopy();
        root.AddChild(new Node(null));

        var actual = root.Count != copyNode.Count;

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(true, actual);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Node_Search_ReturnsAllElements()
    {
        // Arrange
        const int EXPECTED_CHILDREN_COUNT = 3;

        var root = new Node(null);

        var root_child1 = new Node(null);
        var root_child2 = new Node(null);
        var root_child3 = new Node(null);

        // Act
        root.AddChild(root_child1);
        root.AddChild(root_child2);
        root.AddChild(root_child3);

        int actual = root.Count;

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(EXPECTED_CHILDREN_COUNT, actual);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Node_RecursiveSearch_ReturnsAllElements()
    {
        // Arrange
        const int EXPECTED_CHILDREN_COUNT = 9;

        var root = new Node("Root node");

        var rc1 = new Node("[Gen 1] 1st child of: root");
        var rc2 = new Node("[Gen 1] 2nd child of: root");
        var rc3 = new Node("[Gen 1] 3rd child of: root");

        var rc2_1 = new Node("[Gen 2] 1st child of: root's 2nd child");
        var rc2_2 = new Node("[Gen 2] 2nd child of: root's 2nd child");
        var rc3_1 = new Node("[Gen 2] 1st child of: root's 3rd child");

        var rc2_1_1 = new Node("[Gen 3] 1st child of: root's 2nd child's 1st child");
        var rc3_1_1 = new Node("[Gen 3] 1st child of: root's 3rd child's 1st child");

        var rc3_1_1_1 = new Node("[Gen 4] 1st child of: root's 3rd child's 1st child's 1st child");

        // Act
        rc2_1.AddChild(rc2_1_1);
        rc2.AddChild(rc2_1);
        rc2.AddChild(rc2_2);

        rc3_1_1.AddChild(rc3_1_1_1);
        rc3_1.AddChild(rc3_1_1);
        rc3.AddChild(rc3_1);

        root.AddChild(rc1);
        root.AddChild(rc2);
        root.AddChild(rc3);

        int actual = new List<Node>(root.GetChildrenRecursive()).Count;

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(EXPECTED_CHILDREN_COUNT, actual);
    }
}
```

Comment: @dfhwze I'm sure there is a better/faster alternative to my approach to this.

Comment: @dfhwze Thinking now, If I don't find anything related to it in the MS assemblies, I'll just remove the tag

Comment: @dfhwze removed it

Comment: meanwhile, I answered your question :) Btw, good to see unit tests in a question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Reading Material

> *..  any reading material about searching algorithms on trees*

These are the most common tree walkers:

- [Breadth-First Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)
- [Depth-First Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)

---

### Review

There is a bug with IsRoot. Also, why not provide a property `Root { get; }`?

> *if the parent is the root of the tree, then the parent is set to null*
>
> `public bool IsRoot { get { return Parent != null; } }`

You should also take advantage of the sweet syntactic sugar of the language (for all your properties):

```
 public bool IsRoot => Parent == null;
```

---

Since `Children` is private and you always instantiate a list, there is no reason to use null-propagation here:

> `public int Count { get { return Children?.Count ?? 0; } }`

```
public int Count => Children.Count;
```

---

`AddChild` should throw exceptions on invalid input. You don't check for an invalid tree, what if the `node` is a *grand-parent* of the the current instance? Perform similar checks for `RemoveChild`.

```
public void AddChild(Node node)
{
    node = node ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(node));
    if (IsAncestorOrSelf(node)) // <- you should implement such method
        throw new ArgumentException("The node can not be an ancestor or self");
    if (IsDescendant(node)) // <- you should implement such method
        throw new ArgumentException("The node can not be a descendant");
    node.Parent = this;
    Children.Add(node);
}
```

---

`GetChildren` should return an immutable copy of the list containing the children.

```
public IEnumerable<Node> GetChildren()
{
    return Children.ToArray();
}
```

---

I don't know why you would need `DeepCopy` functionality.

---

`GetChildrenRecursive` should be called `GetDescendants`. I would implement it using recursion. This is implemented as depth-first (DFS).

```
public IEnumerable<Node> GetDescendants()
{
    foreach (var child in Children)
    {
         yield return child;
         foreach (var descendant in child.GetDescendants())
         {
              yield return descendant;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time and reviewing the code. Apparently I was paranoid that my first implementation of this method would mess up with the original object. I fixed the following: A) IsRoot code (now, if the parent is not set, then it's considered as the root `Parent == null`; B) Removed the null check on Children; C) Search method now returns immutable copies of the descendants

Comment: I used recursion in _GetDescendants_ because you have tagged your question as such. It is also possible without. I am sure someone will review that part.

Comment: Ok. About the addition of new children, I'm doing the following check: `return !node.Children.Contains(this) && node != this && !Children.Contains(node);`. If it's false, then ArgumentException is thrown.

Comment: Once this question has sufficient answers, you can always ask a follow-up question with the new code. I will be happy review that question as well. For now, I can say, this new check does not cover all edge cases :)

Comment: I was worried about changing the code (which isn't allowed here). As you said, once there are sufficient suggestions, I'll do a follow-up. And again, thanks for you time spent into this matter :)

Answer (score 8):

> ```
> public Node DeepCopy()
> {
>     var other = (Node)MemberwiseClone();
>
>     other.Children = new List<Node>(collection: Children);
>     other.Parent = Parent?.DeepCopy();
>     other.Value = new Node(value: Value);
>
>     return other;
> }
> ```

You should be careful when using this, because it actually clones the entire tree (via `Parent` and `Children`). Besides that, I think `MemberwiseClone` copies the `Children` and `Parent` recursively. So by creating a new list for the `Children` and calling `DeepCopy()` on the `Parent` you actually get a mix of copies and existing `Node` objects, that can lead to unexpected behavior if you change either the copy or the original later on. And the child instances (`other`) will not be part of the parents `Children` list in the copy.

Why does `other.Value` become a `Node(Value)`? - `Value` is by the way also covered by `MemberwiseClone`.

Consider if it is of any use and possibly skip it. I can't see any use of it?

---

> ```
> public void RemoveChild(Node node)
> {
>     if (node != this && Children.Contains(node))
>     {
>         Children.Remove(node);
>     }
> }
> ```

It is safe to call `Children.Remove(node)` even if `node` is not in the list or is `null`, so you can omit the `Contains()` check. `node != this` - I suppose this should be avoided in the `Add` method - but why can't `this` be removed if provided as `node`? You could consider to return the `bool` values returned from `Children.Remove(node)`, to let the client known if the operation was succesful or not.

---

You could consider to make the `Node` class generic:

```
public class Node<T>
{
    public T Value { get; }
    ...
}
```

---

As of `GetChildrenRecursive()` it seems to work, but looks rather complicated as a BFS algorithm. Remember that you have private access to the properties and fields of `Node` instances, so you can for instance call `Children` on any `Node` not just `this`. Below is a revised version, that is a little easier to follow:

```
  public IEnumerable<Node> GetChildrenRecursive()
  {
    if (!HasChildren) yield break;

    Queue<Node> queue = new Queue<Node>(this.Children);

    while (queue.Count > 0)
    {
      var node = queue.Dequeue();
      yield return node;

      if (node.HasChildren)
      {
        foreach (Node child in node.Children)
        {
          queue.Enqueue(child);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

It uses `yield return` instead of creating a concrete `List<Node>` object which is more in line with the return value `IEnumerable<Node>`.

Comment: I think he meant _GetChildrenRecursive_ as search function :) btw I reached my vote limit of today :(

Comment: @Henrik Hansen *GetChildrenRecursive()* is the method I'm talking about, if you are doing this because I got something mixed up (**I can't blame you**), then that went completely over my head. As of the *DeepCopy(Node)*, I removed it, there was no use to it. And I'm planning to make this a generic type, I used the `object` type because gave more freedom over what can be inserted in the tree.

Comment: And I will remove the null check when removing nodes

Comment: Node<T> can always be used as Node<object> if you need to. So making it generic can't hurt your design.